# Twig template inheritence overrides not rendering

Tags: php, twig

I am pretty new to twig and have been giving it a go. Everything was fine until template overrides, and I can't seem for the life of me to figure out why.

Link to twig documentation for what I want to accomplish http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#template-inheritance

**index.php**

```
<?php
//get twig instance
require_once 'Twig/autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();


//declare template directory
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
$twig   = new Twig_Environment($loader);


echo $twig->render('base.twig');
```

**base.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
     {% block content %}
        <p>Default content block</p>
     {% endblock %}
    </body>
 </html>
```

**override.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.twig'%}
{% block content %}
  <p>Content block override</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**Project Folder Structure**
- ProjectFolder

- Twig (the library)
- templates

  -- base.twig

  -- override.twig
- index.php

Comment: What's the error message ?

Comment: No error, just no render

Answer (score 0):

You have to render `override.twig`.

```
[...]
echo $twig->render('override.twig');
```

Like that, Twig will enter to `override.twig` and it will compute the `extends` instruction. There isn't any magic here. Twig will **NOT** search other files for extends.

Comment: Rendering override.twig would defeat the purpose of inheritance  a provided in their documentation. 
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#template-inheritance

Comment: No, you have to use inheritance in Twig like that. In the link that you provide: `The extends tag is the key here. It tells the template engine that this template "extends" another template. When the template system evaluates this template, first it locates the parent.` It's clearly specific that it's when the system evaluates this template and not its parent. It doesn't work in the other way.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but I guess I am not understanding.  several tuts I see show the parent template able to render child template blocks, and able to do the reverse with {[parent () ]} when its inside the block  (which i can get the reverse to render).

Comment: You can take the thing differently. You can extends a lot of times the same template. How would you like that Twig take the **good** child? It's the same notion as OOP in programming, a class can be extended by a lot of other class. If you create a new object of the parent class, the children class will not be checked.